# Transition rule priority and set pattern matching in K?

Tags: kframework

With non-deterministic rules, is there a way to prioritise certain rules until they cannot be applied anymore before applying other rules?

e.g. In the following rules (in pseudocode)

```
1. (S U {P | Q}) => (S U {P, Q}) [prioritise]
2. (S U {P + Q}) => (S U {P})    [transition]
3. (S U {P + Q}) => (S U {Q})    [transition]
```

the intention is to prioritise non-deterministic structural rules such as (1) before non-deterministically applying rules (2) and (3). i.e. if negative pattern-matching is allowed, only apply (2) and (3) if nothing in `S` is of the form `P|Q`. If I'm not mistaken, I could achieve a similar effect using functions, but I was wondering if there is more direct way.

Also, somewhat related to the rules above, is the following the correct syntax to find multiple elements of the form `A + _`?

```
<myset> ... SetItem(A + B) SetItem(A + C)... </myset>
```

Is it possible to update them then?

```
<myset> ... (SetItem(A + B)=>SetItem(B)) (SetItem(A + C)=>SetItem(C))... </myset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, the `transition` attribute is *deprecated*, so does not mean anything on the modern K backends.

We do support exactly what you need via the `priority(...)` attribute. You can do:

```
rule [one]:   (S U {P | Q}) => (S U {P, Q}) [priority(25)]
rule [two]:   (S U {P + Q}) => (S U {P})    [priority(26)]
rule [three]: (S U {P + Q}) => (S U {Q})    [priority(26)]
```

This will ensure that rule `one` is always tried *before* rules `two` or `three` are tried. This works on both the LLVM (concrete execution) and Haskell (symbolic execution) backends, and it works for both normal rules and function rules. Note that because the Haskell backend must do an exhaustive search through the state-space, if it cannot prove that a lower priority rule covers *all* possible behaviors, it will still try higher priority rules on the remainder that is not covered by the lower priority rules.

Priorities can be between `0` and `200` (inclusive).

You can also use the `owise` attribute, which is basically a synonym for `priority(200)`.

The default priority of most rules is `50`. Some specific automatically generated rules get priority `100`.

Comment: thank you for the reply. If [transition] is deprecated, does this mean the --search option automatically does non-deterministic branching on all applicable rules? For symbolic execution, for instance, I may need to expand the entire computation tree of a term. Particularly, I'm interested in expanding all traces, not just one possible run.

Comment: Yes, on the haskell backend, --search will automatically explore all transitions of all rules

Comment: thanks. is there a way to control which transitions are expanded non-deterministically and which ones don't? For instance, I might have a function `F( SetItem(E) S:Set)`. The intention is to non-deterministically expand all rules, but some, ones which call `F`, are meant to be structural and not produce more paths. Would a rule that applies `F` be expanded non-deterministically on every instance of `E` in `S`? If so, is there syntax to avoid that and tell krun to sometimes stay within the current path as if --search wasn't on?

Comment: You can use `Set2List` to turn it into a list so that you deterministically explore the elements of the `Set` without branching on every choice.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Deterministic behaviour has to be defined by the user.